# Exerxise 3, chapter 4 of algebraic topology by Hatcher, Page 358

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am stuck on the following problem:

For an H-space $(X, x_0)$ with multiplication $\mu: X \times X  \to X$, show that the group operation in $\pi_n(X, x_0)$ can also be defined by the rule $(f+g)(x)= \mu(f(x), g(x))$.

I have shown that this a binary operation and the constant map work as the identity element. But, I am not able to find the inverse of an element.

Can you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

$\gamma^{-1}(x)=\gamma(1-x)$ is generally the loop traversed in the opposite direction for elements $\gamma\in \pi _1(X,x_0) $

For $\pi_n, n\gt 1 $ there is the map $\gamma^{-1}(t_1,\dots,  t_n)= \gamma(1-t_1,t_2,\dots ,t_n)$...

Comment: Thanks! But how we can show that $\mu(f(x), f^{-1}(x))$ is homotopic to constant map?

Comment: @Amitk. In an H-space multiplication and composition are "compatible"...  i.e. $f\cdot g \circ  h\cdot  k=f\circ h \cdot g \circ k $...  try using this. ..

Comment: Substitute concatenation for composition in my last comment. ..

Comment: Thanks. Now I got this.